# argparse argument order

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, keyword-argument

I have a little problem.

I use `argparse` to parse my arguments, and it's working very well.

To have the args, I do :

```
p_args = parser.parse_args(argv)
args = dict(p_args._get_kwargs())
```

But the problem with `p_args` is that I don't know how to get these arguments ordered by their position in the command line, because it's a dict.

So is there any possibility to have the arguments in a tuple/list/ordered dict by their order in the command line?

Comment: It would help to see the code showing how you have set up your parser.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To keep arguments ordered, I use a custom action like this:

```
import argparse
class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if not 'ordered_args' in namespace:
            setattr(namespace, 'ordered_args', [])
        previous = namespace.ordered_args
        previous.append((self.dest, values))
        setattr(namespace, 'ordered_args', previous)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test1', action=CustomAction)
parser.add_argument('--test2', action=CustomAction)
```

To use it, for example:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--test2', '2', '--test1', '1'])
Namespace(ordered_args=[('test2', '2'), ('test1', '1')], test1=None, test2=None)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to know the order in which the arguments appear in your parser, you can set up the parser like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "A cool application.")
parser.add_argument('--optional1')
parser.add_argument('positionals', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--optional2')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.positionals
```

Here's a quick example of running this code:

```
$ python s.py --optional1 X --optional2 Y 1 2 3 4 5
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Note that `args.positionals` is a list with the positional arguments in order. See the [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) for more information.

Comment: I think one ramification of this method is that argparse can't/won't do any validating of 1,2,3,4,5 (ie forcing the user to only enter legal values for optional2). You'd have to run through the values for optional2 in your code and validate them.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit fragile since it relies on understanding the internals of `argparse.ArgumentParser`, but in lieu of rewriting `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args`, here's what I use:

```
class OrderedNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__["_arg_order"] = []
        self.__dict__["_arg_order_first_time_through"] = True
        argparse.Namespace.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        #print("Setting %s -> %s" % (name, value))
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        if name in self._arg_order and hasattr(self, "_arg_order_first_time_through"):
            self.__dict__["_arg_order"] = []
            delattr(self, "_arg_order_first_time_through")
        self.__dict__["_arg_order"].append(name)

    def _finalize(self):
        if hasattr(self, "_arg_order_first_time_through"):
            self.__dict__["_arg_order"] = []
            delattr(self, "_arg_order_first_time_through")

    def _latest_of(self, k1, k2):
        try:
            print self._arg_order
            if self._arg_order.index(k1) > self._arg_order.index(k2):
                return k1
        except ValueError:
            if k1 in self._arg_order:
                return k1
        return k2
```

This works through the knowledge that `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args` runs through the entire option list once setting default values for each argument.  Meaning that user specified arguments begin the first time `__setattr__` hits an argument that it's seen before.

Usage:

```
options, extra_args = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv, namespace=OrderedNamespace())
```

You can check `options._arg_order` for the order of user specified command line args, or use `options._latest_of("arg1", "arg2")` to see which of `--arg1` or `--arg2` was specified later on the command line (which, for my purposes was what I needed: seeing which of two options would be the overriding one).

UPDATE: had to add `_finalize` method to handle pathological case of `sys.argv()` not containing any arguments in the list)

Comment: Well only after messing with my refactoring on this and after running through a bunch of tests I have did I realize that this fundamentally won't work in the case of action='store_const' or action='store_true' etc.. something with add_argument('-f', action='store_true') will not add the -f to the argument order list as argparse doesn't add any value to the namespace until the actual argument is encountered unless 'const' or 'default' parameters are passed to add_argument.  BAH this could have been such an elegant solution..

Answer (score 1):

There is module especially made to handle this :

https://github.com/claylabs/ordered-keyword-args

### without using orderedkwargs module

```
def multiple_kwarguments(first , **lotsofothers):
    print first

    for i,other in lotsofothers:
         print other
    return True

multiple_kwarguments("first", second="second", third="third" ,fourth="fourth" ,fifth="fifth")
```

output:

```
first
second
fifth
fourth
third
```

### On using orderedkwargs module

```
from orderedkwargs import ordered kwargs  
@orderedkwargs  
def mutliple_kwarguments(first , *lotsofothers):
    print first

    for i, other in lotsofothers:
        print other
    return True


mutliple_kwarguments("first", second="second", third="third" ,fourth="fourth" ,fifth="fifth")
```

Output:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

Note: Single asterik is required while using this module with decorator above the function.

Comment: I forked it to handle kwargs as OrderedDict in the function header and *identical syntax* in the function body as with the **kwargs case. See
https://github.com/zellerede/Ordered-Keyword-Args/tree/OrderedDict.

Comment: @Berci Nice, you can make pull request also if you would like to.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about command-line argument parsing with argparse, not about function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this because, for logging purposes, I liked to print the arguments after they were parsed. The problem was that the arguments are not printed in order, which was really annoying.

The custom action class just flat out did not work for me. I had other arguments which used a different action such as `'store_true'` and `default` arguments also don't work since the custom action class is not called if the argument is not given in the command line. What worked for me was creating a wrapper class like this:

```
import collections

from argparse import ArgumentParser

class SortedArgumentParser():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ap = ArgumentParser(*args, **kwargs)
        self.args_dict = collections.OrderedDict()      

    def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ap.add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
        # Also store dest kwarg
        self.args_dict[kwargs['dest']] = None

    def parse_args(self):
        # Returns a sorted dictionary
        unsorted_dict = self.ap.parse_args().__dict__
        for unsorted_entry in unsorted_dict:
            self.args_dict[unsorted_entry] = unsorted_dict[unsorted_entry]

        return self.args_dict
```

The pros are that the `add_argument` method should have the exact same functionality as the original `ArgumentParser`. The cons are that if you want other methods you will have to write wrapped for all of them. Luckily for me all I ever used was `add_argument` and `parse_args`, so this served my purposes pretty well. You would also need to do more work if you wanted to use parent `ArgumentParser`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution based on the existing ones:

```
class OrderedNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__["_order"] = [None]
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        if attr in self._order:
            self.__dict__["_order"].clear()
        self.__dict__["_order"].append(attr)
    def ordered(self):
        if self._order and self._order[0] is None:
            self._order.clear()
        return ((attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self._order)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--test1', default=1)
parser.add_argument('--test2')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--slong', action='store_false')
parser.add_argument('--test3', default=3)

args = parser.parse_args(['--test2', '2', '--test1', '1', '-s'], namespace=OrderedNamespace())

print(args)
print(args.test1)
for a, v in args.ordered():
    print(a, v)
```

Output:

```
OrderedNamespace(_order=['test2', 'test1', 'slong'], slong=False, test1='1', test2='2', test3=3)
1
test2 2
test1 1
slong False
```

It allows actions in add_argument(), which is harder for customized action class solution.