# Find the order of arguments in argparse python3

Tags: python, indexing, arguments, position, argparse

I have this code

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input')
parser.add_argument('--min')
parser.add_argument('--max')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

How can I know the order of arguments ? For example, if I type:

```
python somefile.py --min min --input file.csv
```

How can I know position of `--min` is before `--input` and user didn't type `--max`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9028031/1220305

Comment: It's easy to test `if args.max is None: print('not used')`.  There's nothing the user can provide that will set that attribute to the default default `None.`.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought about that too. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design `argparse` is supposed to handle the `optionals` in any order.  They are parsed in the order that they are provided in the command line, but it does not keep any record of that order.  `positionals` without a keyword are handled in the order that they are defined by the `add_argument` definitions.

All attributes are added to the `args` Namespace with their defaults at the start of parsing.  And it does this in the `add_argument` order.  In newer Pythons this order is preserved in the `args.__dict__` (which `vars(args)` also shows).

But in `print(args)`, the attributes are displayed in sorted order.  `usage` also preserves the definition order for `optionals`.

So for a sample parser:

```
In [11]: p.print_usage()                                                        
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo FOO] [--test TEST] [--aaa AAA] bar

In [12]: args=p.parse_args(['xxx'])  

In [13]: args                                                                   
Out[13]: Namespace(aaa=None, bar='xxx', foo=None, test=None)  # sorted

In [14]: vars(args)                                                             
Out[14]: {'foo': None, 'bar': 'xxx', 'test': None, 'aaa': None} # definition

In [15]: [a.dest for a in p._actions]                                           
Out[15]: ['help', 'foo', 'bar', 'test', 'aaa']  # definition order
```

So recording the order of occurrence of the arguments in the command line is, with just `argparse`, awkward.  In a sense it goes against the spirit of `optionals`.

Alternatives:

- work directly with the `sys.argv`
- customize the `action` class
- customize the `Namespace` class

---

One other trick comes to mind:

If the `default` is `argparse.SUPPRESS`, the default is not added to `args`.  Then I think the `var(args)` order will be the order in which values are parsed and added.

```
In [16]: for a in p._actions: a.default=argparse.SUPPRESS  
In [24]: args=p.parse_args(['--test', 'ttt','xxx','--foo=3'])                   
In [25]: args                                                                   
Out[25]: Namespace(bar='xxx', foo='3', test='ttt')
In [26]: vars(args)                                                             
Out[26]: {'test': 'ttt', 'bar': 'xxx', 'foo': '3'}
```

---

Users may repeat `optionals`, with repeats over writing previous values.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be tricky to obtain that information from parser itself, but it can be easily obtained from sys.argv:

```
def get_arg_index(args: list, name: str):
    return next((i for i, v in enumerate(args) if v.startswith(name)), None)


print(get_arg_index(sys.argv, "--min"))
print(get_arg_index(sys.argv, "--max"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I will consider it in the future