# How to use subparses for optional positional arguments?

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I have just started working with `argprase`, and have the following example `main.py` which has optional arguments

```
import os
import numpy
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-C','--Chk',type=str, help='Choose arg')
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
 
    if args['Chk'] == 'compo1':
        print('This is test1')
    elif args['Chk'] == 'compo2':
        print('This is test2')
       
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

If I use `python3 main.py -C compo1` I get the desired result, i.e, `This is test1`. Now, I would like to add addtional arguments if `-C compo1` is called. For example `python main.py -C compa1 -d` where, `-d` performs a task, for eg.

```
This is test1 #output for -C compo1
This is sub task from test1 #2nd output when -d is called
```

Also, I would like `-d` to be the flag when `compa2` is called too, but then the output should be different and as specified.

Can anyone suggest how to get additional arguments for optional positional arguments in argparse library ? and can subparses be used for optional arguments and with the same command line flag ?

Comment: Does the ordering of the command line args matter to you? I.e. if your input is `python3 main.py -d -C`, would you allow it?

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnusson, actually no. But for the user if `-C` is called then the next arg should be `-d` to perform the subsequent task.

Answer (score -1):

So the answer from what I can tell is unfortunately no. The argparse module can't distinguish between the orderings which you would like to distinguish between. I did however find some decent workarounds to this issue at

[Find the order of arguments in argparse python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904423/find-the-order-of-arguments-in-argparse-python3)

I coded the following implementation scheme for your setup:

```py
import argparse, sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Usage: [-C CHK -d]")
parser.add_argument('-C','--Chk', type=str, help='Choose arg')
parser.add_argument('-d', default=False, action="store_true", help='d bool of CHK option')
args = parser.parse_args()

def get_arg_index(args: list, name: str):
    return next((i for i, v in enumerate(args) if v.startswith(name)), None)

if args.Chk:
    if args.d:
        # if chk was called with 'd' submodule, check ordering is correct.
        idx_Chk = (get_arg_index(sys.argv, "-C") if "-C" in sys.argv else get_arg_index(sys.argv, "--Chk"))
        idx_d = get_arg_index(sys.argv, "-d")
        assert idx_Chk + 2  == idx_d, \
            "Error. The index of the --foo and -d flags was not separated by exactly one arg. "
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()
```

Since the argparse help won't display the formatting that you're trying to encourage, I'd recommend writing a detailed `description` message to indicate where the `-d` flags go. Hope this helps!