# argparse, create how to loop my command line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

This is the code, the function r is passed 1 argument int.

```
    import pyautogui as P 
    from colorama import *
    import sys
    import os
    import time
    import argparse

    init(autoreset=True)

    class Automate:

          def classify(self):

              parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
              parser.add_argument('-w', '-write', type=str, nargs=1, help='--Ex--')
              parser.add_argument('-s', '-sleep', type=int, nargs=1 , help='--Ex--')
              parser.add_argument('-l', '-local', type=str, nargs=1, help='--Ex--')
              parser.add_argument('-r', '-repeat', type=int, help='--Ex--')

              A = parser.parse_args()

              if A.w:
                 P.typewrite(A.w.replace("_"," "), 0.25)

              elif A.s:
                  time.sleep(A.s[0])

              elif A.l:
                  co = P.locateOnScreen(A.l[0])
                  print(f"{co}")

              elif A.r:
                   pass

    B = Automate()
    B.classify()
```

Help me to get the r command to repeat the commands that you enter through the command line (the commands will vary depending on what the user wants) without creating an infinite loop. Thank you for your attention and help.

```
F:\>python aut.py -write HELLO_WORLD -s 2 -l image.PNG -r 2  #times

F:\>python aut.py -s 2 -w HELLO_WORLD -repeat 3 -l image.PNG  #times

F:\>python aut.py -r 4 -l image.PNG -w HELLO_WORLD -sleep 2  #times
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do but if you want to repeate something then use `for`-loop and maybe `range(A.r)` - ie. `for x in range(A.r):` ? And maybe use `default=1` for `--repeate` and then you can run `for`-loop even if you don't use `-repeate` because it will have value `1`

Comment: simple, each command has a different overhead, so -r must repeat that task a number of times. `Ex: input: -w Hello_World -r 2`
`output: Hello_World Hello_World`

Comment: Put a loop before the other tests, controlled by the `A.r` value.  `for i in range(A.r): <do the rest>`.  You probably should give `-r` a `default=1`.

Comment: I will try it, another question I did tests but when putting several commands apparently only one is executed without any reason. Is there a way to execute all the commands that I pass through the line one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `default=1` for `-repeate` then you can run loop

Use `if` instead of `elif` to run all functions for arguments in one line.

But they will be always executed in order `write`, `sleep`, `local`. To control order probably you would have to change all in arguments. Maybe this can help [argparse argument order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027028/argparse-argument-order)

```
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
  parser.add_argument('-w', '-write', type=str, nargs=1, help='--Ex--')
  parser.add_argument('-s', '-sleep', type=int, nargs=1 , help='--Ex--')
  parser.add_argument('-l', '-local', type=str, nargs=1, help='--Ex--')
  parser.add_argument('-r', '-repeat', type=int, default=1, help='--Ex--')

  A = parser.parse_args()

  for x in range(A.r):

      if A.w:
         P.typewrite(A.w.replace("_"," "), 0.25)

      if A.s:  # use `if` instead of `elif`
          time.sleep(A.s[0])

      if A.l:  # use `if` instead of `elif`
          co = P.locateOnScreen(A.l[0])
          print(f"{co}")
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can use list with arguments

```
 parse_args(["-write", "HELLO_WORLD", "-s", "2", "-l", "image.PNG", "-r", "2"])
```

so you can change your script to run as before

```
  class Automate:
      def classify(self, arguments):

          # ... code ...

          A = parser.parse_args(arguments)

          # ... code ...

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      B = Automate()
      B.classify(sys.argv)
```

And you can also use it in other script

```
 from aut import Automate

 B = Automate()
 B.classify(["-write", "HELLO_WORLD", "-s", "2", "-l", "image.PNG", "-r", "2"]) 
 B.classify(["-s", "2", "-w", "HELLO_WORLD", "-repeat", "3", "-l", "image.PNG"])
 B.classify(["-r", "4", "-l",  "image.PNG", "-w", "HELLO_WORLD", "-sleep", "2"])
```

or using `split(" ")` if you don't use spaces in arguments

```
 from aut import Automate

 B = Automate()
 B.classify("-write HELLO_WORLD -s 2 -l image.PNG -r 2".split(" ")) 
 B.classify("-s 2 -w HELLO_WORLD -repeat 3 -l image.PNG".split(" ")) 
 B.classify("-r 4 -l image.PNG -w HELLO_WORLD -sleep 2".split(" "))
```

Or simply create `.bat` file with

```
python aut.py -write HELLO_WORLD -s 2 -l image.PNG -r 2  #times
python aut.py -s 2 -w HELLO_WORLD -repeat 3 -l image.PNG  #times
python aut.py -r 4 -l image.PNG -w HELLO_WORLD -sleep 2  #times
```

Comment: Thanks your answer solved my main question,
Since you are here, I want to ask you another situation that came up and that is that only one command is being executed and not how I chain them: Ex
`F: \> python aut.py -write HELLO_WORLD -s 2 -l image.PNG -r 2`
just run `-write`. I'm reading the documentation and can't find the solution. Thanks

Comment: use `if` instead of `elif`