# Executing argparse Arguments in order they are passed in terminal / cmd

Tags: python-3.x, class, cmd, terminal, argparse

I have a data augmentation script that has a class with a bunch of optional methods that are triggered by argparse arguments. I am curious how I can structure my code to process the argparse commands based on the order they are passed in from the terminal.

Goal: If I were to pass arguments as: python maths.py --add --multiply I would want it to add 10 first then multiply by 5 second.
If I were to pass arguments as: python maths.py --multiply --add I would want it to multiply 5 first then add 10.

For example:

```
class Maths:
      def __init__(self):
          self.counter = 0

      def addition(self, num):
          self.counter += num
          return self

      def multiply(self, num):
          self.counter *= num
          return self

 
def main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--add', required = False, action = 'store_true')
        parser.add_argument('--multiply', required = False, action = 'store_true')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        maths = Maths()
        maths.addition(10)
        maths.multiply(5)
        print(maths.counter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

How can I accomplish ordering based on the order of how the arguments are passed in? Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027028/argparse-argument-order

Comment: `argparse` is not a good parser for this purpose.  All the suggestions in the link are fighting the inherently unordered nature of the `args` namespace.  If there is an order it's determined by the `add_argument` commands and their defaults.  User values just overwrite those defaults.

Comment: @hpaulj do you have any recommendations for making this structure more variable? The case is that I have different augmentation methods and using them in different orders produces different results. I'd like to make it dynamic from the user's standpoint.

Comment: I just thought of a couple of ways of collecting the inputs in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parser provides two ways of inputing lists of strings:

```
In [10]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    ...: parser.add_argument('--cmds', nargs='*', choices=['add','mult']) 
    ...: parser.add_argument('--add', dest='actions', action='append_const', const='add') 
    ...: parser.add_argument('--multiply', dest='actions', action = 'append_const', const='mult') 
    ...: parser.print_help() 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                             
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--cmds [{add,mult} [{add,mult} ...]]] [--add]
                [--multiply]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --cmds [{add,mult} [{add,mult} ...]]
  --add
  --multiply
```

As values of a '--cmds' argument:

```
In [11]: parser.parse_args('--cmds mult add'.split())                                                
Out[11]: Namespace(actions=None, cmds=['mult', 'add'])
```

As separate flagged arguments:

```
In [12]: parser.parse_args('--mult --add'.split())                                                   
Out[12]: Namespace(actions=['mult', 'add'], cmds=None)
```

In both cases I create a list of strings.  In the second the `const` values could be functions or methods.

```
const=maths.addition
```

Comment: This looks real good. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and see if it solves my question for certain.