# Preserving the order of user-provided parameters with Python Click

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am trying to port an `argparse` command-line interface (CLI) to `click`. This CLI must maintain the order in which parameters are provided by the user. With the `argparse` version, I used [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9028031/5666087) to maintain order. With `click`, I am not sure how to do this.

I tried creating a custom callback to store params and values in order, but if a parameter is used multiple times, the callback fires the first time it sees a matching parameter.

```py
import click
import typing

class OrderParams:
    _options: typing.List[typing.Tuple[click.Parameter, typing.Any]] = []

    @classmethod
    def append(cls, ctx: click.Context, param: click.Parameter, value: typing.Any):
        cls._options.append((param, value))

@click.command()
@click.option("--animal", required=True, multiple=True, callback=OrderParams.append)
@click.option("--thing", required=True, multiple=True, callback=OrderParams.append)
def cli(*, animal, thing):
    click.echo("Got this order of parameters:")
    for param, value in OrderParams._options:
        print("  ", param.name, value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

#### Current output:

```
$ python cli.py --animal cat --thing rock --animal dog
Got this order of parameters:
   animal ('cat', 'dog')
   thing ('rock',)
```

#### Desired output:

```
$ python cli.py --animal cat --thing rock --animal dog
Got this order of parameters:
   animal 'cat'
   thing 'rock'
   animal 'dog'
```

The [click documentation describes the behavior](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#callback-evaluation-order) that a callback is called once the first time a parameter is encountered, even if the parameter is used multiple times.

> If an option or argument is split up on the command line into multiple places because it is repeated [...] the callback will fire based on the position of the first option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by over riding the `click.Command` argument parser invocation using a custom class like:

#### Custom Class:

```
class OrderedParamsCommand(click.Command):
    _options = []

    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        # run the parser for ourselves to preserve the passed order
        parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
        opts, _, param_order = parser.parse_args(args=list(args))
        for param in param_order:
            type(self)._options.append((param, opts[param.name].pop(0)))

        # return "normal" parse results
        return super().parse_args(ctx, args)
```

#### Using Custom Class:

Then to use the custom command, pass it as the `cls` argument to the `command` decorator like:

```
@click.command(cls=OrderedParamsCommand)
@click.option("--animal", required=True, multiple=True)
@click.option("--thing", required=True, multiple=True)
def cli(*, animal, thing):
    ....
```

#### How does this work?

This works because `click` is a well designed OO framework.  The `@click.command()` decorator
usually instantiates a `click.Command` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with
the `cls` parameter.  So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Command` in our
own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Command.parse_args()` and run the parser ourselves to preserve
the order passed in.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

class OrderedParamsCommand(click.Command):
    _options = []

    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
        opts, _, param_order = parser.parse_args(args=list(args))
        for param in param_order:
            type(self)._options.append((param, opts[param.name].pop(0)))

        return super().parse_args(ctx, args)


@click.command(cls=OrderedParamsCommand)
@click.option("--animal", required=True, multiple=True)
@click.option("--thing", required=True, multiple=True)
def cli(*, animal, thing):
    click.echo("Got this order of parameters:")
    for param, value in OrderedParamsCommand._options:
        print("  ", param.name, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli('--animal cat --thing rock --animal dog'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
Got this order of parameters:
   animal cat
   thing rock
   animal dog
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. i modified this slightly by setting `self._options = []` in `OrderedParamsCommand.parse_args()` to avoid potential clashes if i use the same command class in multiple commands. then, in `cli`, i used `ctx.command.options` to get the values from the instance.  _This works because `click` is a well designed OO framework_ -- i've seen this in your other answers ;)

Comment: @jakub If you think there is a chance of the class being used twice in the same context (which is generally not the case with click), put the list on `self` and then access as `cli._options`.

Comment: i parameterized a test of my cli with pytest, and the class was being used multiple times in the same context

Comment: This doesn't work when the script is called without arguments, there should be a type check for `opts[param.name]`. I have proposed edits. EDIT: I cannot :(

Answer (score 1):

@StephenRauch's answer is correct but it misses one minor detail. Calling the `cli` function i.e. the script without any arguments will result in an error:

```
type(self)._options.append((param, opts[param.name].pop(0)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

The fix for this is checking `opts[param.name]` if it is not `None`. The modified `OrderedParamsCommand` looks like:

```py
class OrderedParamsCommand(click.Command):
    _options = []

    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        # run the parser for ourselves to preserve the passed order
        parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
        opts, _, param_order = parser.parse_args(args=list(args))
        for param in param_order:
            # Type check
            option = opts[param.name]
            if option != None:
                type(self)._options.append((param, option.pop(0)))

        # return "normal" parse results
        return super().parse_args(ctx, args)
```

EDIT: I posted an answer as I could not propose an edit

**EDIT 2: Uhh, this should not be the solution. I just tried `--help` with this and it crashed with this error:**

```
type(self)._options.append((param, option.pop(0)))
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Too bad, I wished there is a proper solution